# Call few contract methods from another contract consistently

Tags: solidity, delegatecall

Can I call a few contract methods from another contract consistently in one block? The order of methods calls is important!

```
if (contract.method1.value(msg.value)()) {
   contract.method2(someValue);
}
```

Comment: Not only can you call them in one block, but you cannot call them in more than one block. A transaction never spans over several blocks.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

The single call to your outer contract will send messages to your inner contracts in exactly the order you expect, every time. They will always execute in the same block because the whole thing is encapsulated in the single transaction to your outer contract, which must be mined in a single block.

Although there is a mining delay before the outer transaction is included in a block, the inner messages are part of it and their execution can be thought of as roughly instantanious.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @rob-hitchers, thank you for the answer. I'll describe my problem in detail. I am trying to call one contract from another In TRON blockchain. `method2(...)` transfers TRX to the caller, so as I see from transactions `method1(...)` was executed, but when `method2(...)` tries to send TRX to my caller contract - transaction was broken with an error `FAIL-REVERT OPCODE EXECUTED`.